# Adding multiple line items on a single submit, Spree 3, RoR 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

CONTEXT INFO: Hi, I have a rails 5.0.3 app working with Spree 3.2.0.rc1 gem, every feature is working fine, and i've only modified some views.

OBJECTIVE: My store sells fewer than 12 variants in total, so I would like to have a quicker way for my customers to add items to the cart.

QUESTION: How can I modify the shopping cart, so that I can add multiple line items to the cart with different submit buttons

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For achieving your goal you can create a separate action in `checkout controller` say `checkout` and define your logic there.

It would look something like the code snippet given below

```
def checkout
  order = current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true)
  errors = []
  Variant.all.each do |variant|
    begin
      order.contents.add(variant)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      errors << e.record.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    end
  end
  if errors.present?
    flash[:error] = errors
    redirect_back_or_default(spree.root_path)
  else
    flash[:success] = 'All Products added'
    respond_with(order) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_path }
    end
  end
end
```

You can still refactor this code by moving

```
  Variant.all.each do |variant|
    begin
      order.contents.add(variant)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      errors << e.record.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    end
  end
```

this logic as a class method in `variant model`.

Please let me know if you still face any issues

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't what I had in mind, but I'm sure this will be helpful in the future! 
what I ended up doing, was to modify the singleton page in order to display it as a partial for each product, that way I can add any variant of any product directly from the home page.